# How to get VS Code debug data like breakpoints, steps, line code

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an academic software visualization project that aims to capture debug sessions and display graphically.
For this, I am trying to create a Visual Studio Code Extension where I can get the data exchanged with the current language debugger, such as *added breakpoints, stepsinto, stepsover, debug session start, debug file, context variables, line code debugged*. That is, the same data that is displayed in the VS Code windows: VARIABLES, WATCH, CALL STACK, LOADED SCRIPTS and BREAKPOINTS.

I tried to create an extension that adds a new **Debugger Provider**, using Debug Adapter (DAP - Debug Adapter Protocol). However this cancels the current provider and does not allow debugging.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension

I also tried using the **VS Code API** events.
With these events I managed to control the start of the session and some breakpoint data, however incomplete.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug

Would anyone know how to capture this debugging data in the VS Code scope (**VS Code Generic Debugger UI**), that is, regardless of the language used?
Is there any open issue for this in VS Code's GitHub?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Having written a debug adapter myself, I believe the communication between vscode and the adapter is purely restricted to these 2 components and cannot be intercepted or read by any other code part.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want to visualize the data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution for this is called a `DebugAdapterTracker`.

```
vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory('*', {
  createDebugAdapterTracker(session: DebugSession) {
    return {
      onWillReceiveMessage: m => console.log(`> ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`),
      onDidSendMessage: m => console.log(`< ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`)
    };
  }
});
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_extension-authoring

Look for "Finalized Debug Adapter Tracker API". It was originally created for Live Share debugging.