# How can I listen for debug adapter protocol events in a vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I know I can send custom request to the debug adapter using `vscode.debug.activeDebugSession?.customRequest(command)`. But what if I want to listen for an event such as [Stopped Event](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Events_Stopped)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For custom events, use this:

```js
vscode.debug.onDidReceiveDebugSessionCustomEvent(event => {
    if(event.event == 'stopped') {
        // ...
    }
})
```

For events intercepted by vscode, you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63657824/5744858) instead:

> The solution for this is called a `DebugAdapterTracker`.
>
> ```js
> vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterTrackerFactory('*', {
>   createDebugAdapterTracker(session: DebugSession) {
>     return {
>       onWillReceiveMessage: m => console.log(`> ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`),
>       onDidSendMessage: m => console.log(`< ${JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)}`)
>     };
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_extension-authoring
>
> Look for "Finalized Debug Adapter Tracker API". It was originally
> created for Live Share debugging.